# Flush in Texas holdem

Tags: poker-theory

How is it decided in Texas holdem which flush is higher, if the five highest cards in the flush are community cards and then each of the players has another card of the same suit, but lower than all of the cards on the table? Would the five card rule apply and so it would be a draw, or would the player with the higher card in his hands win?

Comment: Only 5 cards are considered for every hand, regardless having a full-house or flush or an A-high. You just combine your 5 best from community and hole cards (7 in number, in texas holdem).

Comment: It seems like 20% of the questions on this site are about the five card rule. Apparently hard to grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A poker hand is only five cards, so it's a split pot.